Wifi calling on 2nd Sim [Jio-India] stopped working
I have a Samsung M33 5G .
I use 2 sims .
After factory resetting my phone wifi calling works well on both the sims .
But soon after the sim 2 stops using wifi calling.
My sim 2 is jio 5g sim.
Video
I tried different methods even aeroplane mode , turning sim on and off ,restarting the phone , also swaping the sim slots of both the phones , it still doesn't work.
